# D'alembert's approach for boundary value problems

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I have the following problem

$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
u_{t t}=u_{x x}+2 u, \quad t>0, \quad 0<x<\pi \\
\left.u\right|_{t=0}=0,\left.\quad u_{t}\right|_{t=0}=0 \\
\left.u_{x}\right|_{x=0}=1,\left.u_{x}\right|_{x=\pi}=1
\end{array}\right.$

It is clear that it needs to use D'Alembert's approach:

$u(x, t)=\frac{\varphi(x+a t)+\varphi(x-a t)}{2}+\frac{1}{2 a} \int_{x-a t}^{x+a t} \psi(\alpha) d \alpha$

where

$u(x, 0)=\varphi(x), \quad u_{t}(x, 0)=\psi(x)$

In my case I have $\varphi(x) = \psi(x) = 0$. What id does mean and how to solve the problem in this case? And also, how to treat this term $2u$ in the equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D'Alembert's solution is hardly adapted to solve the wave equation with an additional term $2u$. Instead, let us use separation of variables. To do so, we need to substract the stationary solution
$$
u^*(x) = \frac{\sin(x\sqrt{2}) - \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \cos(x\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
by introducing $v = u^* + u$. Thus, $v$ satisfies the PDE problem $v_{tt} = v_{xx} + 2 v$ with homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions, and with the initial conditions $v = u^*$ and $v_t = 0$ at $t=0$.
Separation of variables $v(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ gives
$$
T'' + \lambda T = 0, \qquad  X'' + (\lambda+2)X = 0
$$
where $\lambda$ is the separation constant. For $\lambda >0$, solutions are of the form
\begin{aligned}
T(t) &= A \cos(t\sqrt{\lambda}) + B \sin(t\sqrt{\lambda})\\
X(x) &= C \cos(x\sqrt{\lambda+2}) + D \sin(x\sqrt{\lambda+2})
\end{aligned}
Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks, but I have seen that this method is applied in case of zeros in boundary conditions. Should I firstly make a "shift" of the problem to obtain zeros at boundaries? Or it ok to apply it where it is just same constants at boundaries?

Comment: @ConstantinWerner Oops sorry -- you are right; Answer updated!